# Renaming tags to plurals

Tags: discussion, support, tagging

(Edit by KennyTM: Just a reminder, please avoid retagging for pluralization before there is consensus, thanks.)

---

I propose the following changes in tags:

- [lie-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lie-algebra) ===> [lie-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lie-algebras)
- [riemann-surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riemann-surface) ===> [riemann-surfaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riemann-surfaces)
- [sigma-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sigma-algebra) ===> [sigma-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sigma-algebras)
- [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequality) ===> [inequalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inequalities)
- [circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circle) ===> [circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circles)
- [manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifold) ===> [manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifolds)

And possibly:

- [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) ===> [definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definitions)
- [paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paradox) ===> [paradoxes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paradoxes)
- [limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit) ===> [limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits)
- [fun-problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fun-problem) ===> [fun-problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fun-problems)
- [puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle) ====> [puzzles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzles)
- [open-problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-problem) ===> [open-problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-problems)

There are two tags which I am not sure of: [number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) and [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof). These could perhaps be renamed to plurals. But perhaps these tags can simply be done without.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tag synonym feature. I suggest we use that instead of retagging.

Please read this for more info on tag synonyms: [Could the tagging system be enhanced to support tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms/56992#56992)

Comment: Well I think we do not need two tags to express the same thing. There are already many tags and allow simple variations will make everything more confusing. Also, should be easy to a moderator to change this. I believe that the important thing here is to decide whether or not we want some of them in the plural.

Comment: @Nuno: Do you know how the tag synonym feature works?

Comment: No. But will be glad if you explain ;). I believe that there will be two tags and when we search the system will display all questions with one of both.

Comment: @Nuno: We can create an equivalence class of tags, with one representative/master tag for each class. Whenever anyone uses a tag, it is replaced by the master. This works not only for the past incorrectly tagged questions (the software takes care of that), but also in future, automatically, without the need for moderator intervention every few months. In effect there will only be one tag. See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms/56992#56992

Comment: @Moron: Ah! That's even better than I thought. So we just need to select the representatives of the tags. Thanks for your explanation. Now I totally agree with you.

Comment: So if everyone agree, we should create something like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms

Comment: Moron, you forget a small detail. To propose a new synonym class, the representative _must be the most used one._ This makes your idea unfeasible. @Nuno: no need, there's [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) already. What you linked to is a relic of the past, back when synonyms weren't implemented.

Comment: @bapd: Thanks for this information. It was very helpful.

Comment: @badp: Hmm...In any case, that is a one time moderator effort, I suppose.

Comment: @badp: btw, where does it say that? Can you please provide me a link? I thought the tag synonym voting system didn't need that.

Comment: Sure: [item #2 of this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57479/allowing-users-with-a-nominal-amount-of-rep-to-submit-possible-tag-synonyms-and-v/57983#57983).

Comment: @Badp: Thanks. That seems to be specific to the UI for non-moderator users. Now I wonder, does the software disallow mods from suggesting tags which could have lower question count too?