# About the plurality of tag names

Tags: support, tagging, moderation

It is most appropriate that the tag names of countable nouns should be in plural forms, but there are still quite a lot of tag names which should be in plural forms but they use single forms, for example the [indefinite-integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indefinite-integral) and [definite-integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definite-integral) tags (more examples can be found in e.g. [Renaming tags to plurals](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1194)), compare with the [improper-integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/improper-integrals) tag, this should be a great joke of the Q&A sites industry as it for example appears the double standard of the plurality of tag names.

To solve these problems, for the tags which have very few questions, it is practical to manually retag each questions of the tags, but it is not practical for the tags which have many questions. Another approaches are that first create the plural form tags for some questions, and make the applications of the single form tags merge into the plural form tags, but I am afraid for example there are too few users which can fulfil the minimum requirements for the voting actions of handing the applications so that the applications should take too long time or even impossible to become successful. So the best approaches should be by renaming of those tags. But the tags renamings can only be done by our diamond moderators with just taking some simple processes. But even they are so simple, most diamond moderators are still often not willing to do so and make me disappointed.

Comment: Who cares?....?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: I don't like to see anyone says like "Who cares?" to shirk their owm duties. At least It aren't be good to maintain the good image of Q&A sites industry?

Comment: You are worried about singular and plural tag names, but you can write "it aren't be good". I'm sorry, but I'd put consistency in number in tag names way down on the list of priorities.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Sorry for I may get the wrong gammar of rhetorical questions. It should be "At least It should be good to maintain the good image of Q&A sites industry, shouldn't it?" instead.

Comment: Again, I think there are a lot of things that contribute more to the image of m.se than do the singular-vs-plural tag names. But we'll see what the community thinks.

Answer (score 5):

> But even they are so simple, most diamond moderators are still often not willing to do so and make me disappointed.

On the scale of things (in particular other moderation issues), this is really, really, really, really minor.

We will get to it when we get to it. It will help if people create new tags with the proper "plurality". It will help also if your post your request to [Tag merging and synonyms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms) Some moderators go through the list periodically to see if there are obvious ones that they can fix quickly. (I admit I have been busy the past few months so don't have the time to do so.)

For users with sufficient reputation etc, another option is to propose a tag synonym yourself. Mods can easily merge/swap the "main tag" at a later date.