# Tag cleanup 2014

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

Tags need a regular cleanup.
There was a number of questions on particular tags recently — but (while proposals for some really major changes should, perhaps, be posted as separate questions) maybe a separate question for each case is too much.

In the past we used [Tag merging and synonyms](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1363/) thread — but it grew too cluttered to be of much use.

Rules of the game are basically the same:

- post your suggestion as an answer here if use see

  - a particularly bad tag (rule of thumb from the previous thread: «roughly speaking ... if I can't imagine a person classifying a tag as either interesting or ignored, I'm getting rid of it»),
  - a tag that should be a synonym of an existing one,
  - a tag that used for two or more completely unrelated things;
- upvote/downvote/comment as your agree/disagree with suggestions;
- wait a day or two before implementing suggestion;
- when retagging questions by hand please keep your rate down to a few posts a day, so not to flood the main page.

Comment: (If you think the Tag Merging and Synonyms thread is cluttered, just wait until you get that extra 900 rep and see all the deleted answers!)

Comment: As you write, Tag merging and synonyms thread is quite long. That's why it is useful viewing the answers there [sorted by recent activity](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: @Martin I use sort by recent activity on all question (both here and on main). It doesn't solve all problems (for one thing, there comments are folded immediately — even for answers with only one comment).

Comment: @Martin: I agree with Grigory, with almost 150 answers (included deleted), that thread is just exhausted out. Regardless to how you sort the answers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The two most recent posts there ([1](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12371) and [2](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12364)) received som votes and comments and they were resolved. This at least shows that there are some people who read that thread. (Although it seems that we have digressed from the questions posted by Grigory. If needed, we can continue the discussion about the long thread [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3740/tagging).)

Comment: @Martin: And I still follow that thread. But it's generally difficult to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please vote this up if you think we need a new thread («Tag cleanup 2015»).

Comment: I wanted to do start a new thread with a proposal for a 2015 cleanup thread, and a request that we summarize all the unresolved issues from the current thread, and bang them out as quickly as possible.

Comment: @Asaf Are there any unresolved proposals left here? (Beside just proposed tagging<-tag-management)

Comment: @Asaf Please feel free to edit http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-cleanup-2015

Comment: Well, it's not clear to me that all of them are resolved. Maybe we need to go through those without a "Resolved" banner on top, and see what's up with them.

Comment: @Asaf Oops, there are indeed a lot of unresolved cases... And making synonyms w/o moderator superpowers is hard..

Answer (score 20):

> **Resolved:** Both [homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homology) and [cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cohomology) have been merged into (and made synonyms) of [homology-cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homology-cohomology).

I propose merging [homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homology) and [cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cohomology) into something like, say, [homology-cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homology-cohomology).

Comment: (Or maybe just making one synonym of another...)

Comment: Can you create a [tag:homology-cohomology] tag (by adding it to a question), and then create tag excerpt and and at least a stub of a tag-wiki? After that I can go ahead and merge both [tag:homology] and [tag:cohomology] into the new tag, and make them both synonyms.

Comment: @ArthurFischer [I took the liberty of doing it myself.](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/homology-cohomology/info) It seems to me that [tag:homological-algebra] is more adequate for (co)chain complexes in general, hence the tag wiki I wrote.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Thanks. This seems to have been one of the most popular suggestions here, but I've felt a bit out of my mathematical comfort in keeping things clean while going through with it.

Comment: @Najib, Arthur thank you!

Comment: (I haven't been actively using SE for several months and missed this.)

Answer (score 15):

> **Resolved (for now):** I (Arthur Fischer) made an "executive decision" and went with my own preferred [moment-generating-functns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moment-generating-functns). If there are strong feelings that this is not optimal, feel free to add something to the [Tag Management 2015](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19037) thread.

The tag [moment-generating-funcion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moment-generating-funcion) is misspelled.

Comment: I think the best renaming of it would be `moment-generating-fn`, perhaps.

Comment: `moment-generating-functn` would also fit within the character limit, as would `moment-generating-functns`.

Comment: `moment-generatingfunction` (with apologies to Wilf)?

Comment: `moment-generatin-function` has a certain hayseed charm.

Answer (score 13):

> **Resolved:** It is now [a synonym of field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/field-theory/synonyms).

Do we really need [algebraic-closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-closure)?

(This tag is still at large, can we do something about it?)

Comment: synonym of [tag:field-theory], perhaps?

Answer (score 12):

> **Resolved**

I can't see much good coming out of [nilpotent-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nilpotent-groups).  Most questions will probably be sylow theory questions concluding that a group is nilpotent.  I propose we merge it into [solvable-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solvable-groups).

Comment: It seems as though the [tag:nilpotent-groups] tag is now empty. I'm not sure if anything else should be done here.

Comment: [tag:nilpotent-groups] is gone, but [tag:nilpotence] is around. Do you have any thoughts about this?

Comment: @ArthurFischer Yikes, I don't like that at all.  Nilpotent matrices and nilpotent groups are hardly related, so this mixes apples and oranges, *in addition* to being crappy in the way the old tag was.  I vote to kill it.

Answer (score 11):

> **Resolved**

A new tag [precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/precalculus) was created. It should probably be synonym of [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus).

AFAIK [precalculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precalculus) is American term. That's why I asked [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16000964#16000964) for some feedback from people familiar with American education system. The feedback was that they should be synonyms. (If the new tag is needed at all.) But of course, if there are any reasons why this would not be a correct action, we can discuss it in comment to this post.

EDIT: I have just noticed that this synonym [has already been suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/algebra-precalculus/synonyms). Users with score at leat 5 on the [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) can vote for (or against) this synonym.

Comment: (And precalculus is a relatively meaningless, very general term at that)

Comment: Preschool precalculus is going to be the next big thing.

Answer (score 9):

> **Resolved**

Do we really need [step-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/step-function)?

I'm really asking here, although I can clearly point out that my default view is against new tags, unless evidence shows otherwise (and there is no evidence in this case to begin with).

Comment: I agree, the tag seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: we have one there as `floor- function`

Answer (score 9):

> **Resolved**

Should [biproportionality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biproportionality) be deleted? Just 4 questions tagged...

Comment: With only 4 questions in the tag (and 5 votes in support for its removal), I think the better way to go is to remove it from the questions (fixing other things if applicable). Then the tag gets axed automatically.

Comment: I've retagged 3 questions left by hand

Answer (score 8):

> **Resolved:** [quadratic-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratic-equation) has been made a synonym of [quadratics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratics).

We have two tags [quadratics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratics) and [quadratic-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratic-equation). I think they should be synonyms. (I do not have sufficient reputation in either of the two for suggesting a synonym.)

The [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/quadratics/info) of the first one specifically says that it is for questions about quadratic equations. <s>The second one has empty tag-wiki, but the name of the tag is self-explanatory.</s> So does the second one.

Tag-excerpt history [for quadratics](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/165956/revisions), tag-excerpt history [for quadratic-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/831707/revisions), tag-wiki history [for quadratic-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/831706/revisions). (I have added these links to preserve the tag-excerpts/tag-wikis; since it is difficult to find them once the tag has been removed.)

Comment: Only now I have noticed that synonymizing these two was also suggested in [the old thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/11514#11514).

Comment: Synonym has been suggested. Four upvotes will make it effective.

Comment: Here is [link to the synonym voting page](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/quadratics/synonyms).

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: FYI, when a moderator suggests a synonym, that synonym is made.

Answer (score 8):

> **Resolved:** Synonym approved, and tags merged.

On meta, there are [closing](/questions/tagged/closing) (71 posts) and [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) (13 posts), with identical tag wiki. I think they should be synonymized.

**Update**: seeing 6 upvotes here, I went ahead and [suggested the synonym](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/closing/synonyms). Please vote. (There are now two synonyms there to vote for)

Comment: Speaking about [synonyms of closing](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/closing/synonyms), I think it is worth having ([meta-tag:close-reasons]) as a separated tag. (However, I did not know whether making a separate post in this thread saying *these two tags should not be synonyms* would be an appropriate use of this thread.)

Answer (score 8):

> **Resolved**: both [supremum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supremum)  and [infimum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infimum) are now  synonyms of [supremum-and-infimum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supremum-and-infimum).

[infimum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infimum) is a tag, but [supremum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supremum) is not. Unfair!

I think these *might* be useful since [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis) is huge and [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory) does not quite fit to distinguish these (it fits in principle, but these are analysis questions).  There are 61 questions there.

Maybe rename to [supremum-infimum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supremum-infimum)?

Comment: Seems in the spirit of [tag:limsup-and-liminf]

Comment: The name in the previous comment is now the master synonym for both sup and inf.

Comment: Thursday, is this "going up" from the sup of one set to the inf of another, or "going down" from the sup of a set, to its inf?

Comment: It appears that the [tag:infimum] tag wiki and excerpt were imported into the new tag. I've made fairly trivial edits to both to indicate that both concepts fall under this umbrella tag. An interested party is of course free to improve it further.

Comment: @Arthur: In Soviet Russia, the party is interested in you!

Answer (score 7):

> **Resolved:** [integral-dependance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral-dependance) was merged into (but *not* made a synonym of) [integral-dependence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral-dependence).

Although I don't find necessary a tag like "integral-dependance" I suggest to (remove or) rename it "integral-dependence" which is a more common terminology.

Comment: We definately need to fix this!

Comment: Discussions about the effectiveness of the properly named tag should probably go elsewhere. (I'm not really one to judge.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thanks. I've tried to start a topic on this matter [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16727/is-it-possible-to-change-the-integral-dependance-tag-into-integral-dependence) buy it was closed and I was sent here.

Comment: @user26857: That question appears to be just about correcting the name of the tag (and why I cast a binding vote to close it as a duplicate of this question). It was only in this answer that I saw any indication that even a properly named tag might not be worthwhile. There's a number of answers here about the whether tags should be kept at all, and if you can make a case that it should be removed, please add a new answer explaining why.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Actually my intention was exactly what you done (thank you again), namely renaming the old tag. If it is really useful or not, I don't know, because I'm no so involved with the tagging policy of this site.

Answer (score 6):

> **Resolved:** [co-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-algebra) was pluralised to become [co-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-algebras) and this was merged into and made a synonym of [coalgebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coalgebras).

[co-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-algebra) should become [coalgebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coalgebras)

Comment: Should I take this to mean merging [tag:co-algebra] into a brand-new [tag:coalgebras] and making them synonyms?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I think so

Answer (score 6):

> **Resolved:** Both [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) and [tag-merging](/questions/tagged/tag-merging) have been merged into (and made synonyms of) [tag-management](/questions/tagged/tag-management).

Currently on meta we have both a [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) tag and a [tag-merging](/questions/tagged/tag-merging) tag.  While the operations of tag-synonymising and tag-merging are not the same, they are frequently done in concert and the difference between them may not be fully appreciated by the average user (or even the average meta-user).  (The latter meta-tag is also quite new.)

I suggest that both of these meta-tags be merged into and made synonyms of a new <s>[tag-merging-and-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-merging-and-synonyms)</s> [tag-management](/questions/tagged/tag-management)<sup>1</sup> meta-tag.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Thanks to mau for making [this tag-name suggestion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12485/winter-tag-cleanup#comment49359_12581). Not quite as fun, but likely easier to, errrr, manage.</sub>

Comment: Maybe [tag-headache] instead? :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Now that you (almost) mention it, a [meta-tag:headache] meta-tag might be useful.  Except I'd be tempted to make _every_ meta-tag a synonym of it!

Comment: (tag-management)?

Comment: @mau: At first glance I really like your suggestion.  I'm going to mull it over a little bit further before I edit the post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> **Resolved**: the tag [euler-maclaurin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euler-maclaurin) was cleaned up. To keep it clean,  [maclaurin-expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maclaurin-expansion) was created as a synonym of [taylor-expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taylor-expansion).

Antonio Vargas [pointed out](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13180/127096) that [euler-maclaurin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euler-maclaurin) is misused. I think this is because it's the only tag that comes up when one types "maclaurin" in the tag field.

Proposal: create [maclaurin-expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maclaurin-expansion) as a synonym of the existing [taylor-expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taylor-expansion).

Comment: +1 This would be a great improvement.

Comment: Okay, so I've created the requested synonym.  I also think that all questions currently tagged [tag:euler-maclaurin] are correctly tagged.  So this might be a done deal.

Comment: @ArthurFischer, should tag synonyms come up as suggestions when typing a tag?  When I try to tag something "maclaurin-expansion", the tag that's suggested is "euler-maclaurin".

Answer (score 6):

> **Resolved**

I think that [grammar-extraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-extraction) and [grammar-generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-generalization) might be over specific here, and perhaps should be merged into [formal-grammar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-grammar).

Comment: there are no questions with these tags now

Answer (score 6):

**Resolved**

I suggest [continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuous) should be a synonym for [continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuity).

[Link to voting page for the synonym](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/continuity/synonyms).

Answer (score 6):

Are [maximal-ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maximal-ideals) and [prime-ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prime-ideals) important enough to have separate tags?

If not, maybe the best thing to do would be not to remove the tags, but to create synonyms to [ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ideals). (So if someone in the future wants to create the tags again, he will simply get the question tagged by (ideals).)

At the moment, there are only two questions having these tags:

- [Maximal and prime ideals of $2 \mathbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064801/maximal-and-prime-ideals-of-2-mathbb-z)
- [Looking for example of a commutative non-unital ring in which every maximal ideal is a prime ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064484/looking-for-example-of-a-commutative-non-unital-ring-in-which-every-maximal-idea)

Comment: I have [pinged](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064484/looking-for-example-of-a-commutative-non-unital-ring-in-which-every-maximal-idea?noredirect=1#comment2176956_1064484) also the tag creator. In [his reply](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064484/looking-for-example-of-a-commutative-non-unital-ring-in-which-every-maximal-idea?noredirect=1#comment2177515_1064484) he basically says that he has no problem in going with the majority opinion.

Comment: I agree with adding synonyms.

Comment: There is now a separate question about these tags: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23012/should-we-have-tags-maximal-ideals-and-prime-ideals

Answer (score 5):

What does [kkt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kkt) stand for?

Five questions, no wiki.

Comment: I would guess [Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions). Possible merge into [tag:nonlinear-optimization]?  There is also a [tag:karush-kuhn-tucker] tag, and whatever is done to [tag:kkt] should probably be done to that, as well.

Answer (score 5):

> **Resolved:** The tag [brainteaser](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainteaser) was removed.

The tag-excerpt for [brainteaser](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainteaser) (which was created by [Tunk-Fey](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/920859/revisions)) reads:

> Question about logic puzzles and riddles that requires thinking in unconventional ways with given constraints in mind.

The tag-excerpt for [puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle), which was [created by Asaf Karagila](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/53833/revisions):

> This tag is meant for questions about the mathematical principles behind games, riddles, or their possible solutions. If the answer is known to you please do not use this tag to "riddle" other users, but rather to ask about the correctness of a possible solution or ways to extend and improve an existing solution.

When I read the tag-excerpts, I don't see any substantial difference, so I think the two tags should be synonyms. (However, I do not have enough reputation in the (puzzle) tag to suggest a synonym.)

See also this [related discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17536462#17536462).

Comment: The new tag can be removed altogether, I think.

Comment: One of two questions with a tag needed an edit anyway, so I retagged along the way. Based on votes here, I think there is enough support to remove the tag from the other question as well. (cc: @Asaf)

Comment: @Thursday: Is this a suggestion that I remove the tag?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It *might* be.

Comment: @Thursday: Stop talking in riddles, Monday!

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: Oh, so it's just [tag:recreational-mathematics]? Yeah, brainteaser can go away.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: According to Cambridge dictionary, `puzzle` as a noun means: 1. a situation which is difficult to understand 2. **a game or toy** in which you have to fit separate pieces together, or a problem or question which you have to answer by using your skill or knowledge. `brainteaser` : **a problem** for which it is hard to find the answer, especially one which people enjoy trying to solve as a game. So, using the given definition, which tag should be suitably removed?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: You could have used the edit button. Now it looks like I can go back in time, and I will not hear the end of it. It's enough that I am expected to read minds!

Answer (score 4):

> **Resolved:** The [representation-theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/representation-theorems) tag has been emptied.

[representation-theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/representation-theorems) only consists of one question, but I don't think it's supposed to be [representation-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/representation-theory).  Anybody understand what the question is asking well enough to determine what it *should* be classified under?

Comment: I thought tags used only on one question are deleted automatically?

Comment: @GrigoryM: According to [Willie Wong's answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2829/8348) you're correct. That is, if after 6 months a tag has only been used on a single question, that tag will be removed (see [Jeff Atwood's MSO answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/214632)).

Comment: @GrigoryM Sure but I'm trying to figure out what I should retag it with.

Comment: @Alexander (I'm afraid I can't comprehend that question, but) perhaps asking OP in the comments there might help?..

Comment: The tag [has been removed](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13123/is-the-representation-theorems-tag-necessary).

Answer (score 4):

> **Resolved:** [anniversary](/questions/tagged/anniversary) has been merged into (and made a synonym of) [celebration](/questions/tagged/celebration).

Can [anniversary](/questions/tagged/anniversary) be merged into (and made a synonym of) [celebration](/questions/tagged/celebration)?

Answer (score 4):

What's [research](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research)?

Is it for questions *about* research, or questions which *are* research? Or does it even matter? [read: maybe we should delete the tag altogether]

Comment: Just by the name of tag I'd expect something similar to ([tag:advice]) or ([tag:career-development]). But when I look what kind of questions is in that tag, I see only a few questions like this.

Comment: If we are discussing this tag, we might as well look into ([tag:undergraduate-research]).

Comment: I looked at the questions there ... just delete this thing, along with its little sibling [tag:undergraduate-research]. But maybe they can be untagged manually, without calling in Trogdor? There is career-development for questions about "how do I become an awesome mathematician", and an assortment of other meaningless tags attached to other soft questions. Advice! Learning! Life-Universe-and-Everything!

Answer (score 4):

> **Resolved**

[simplicity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplicity) is the ultimate sophistication, said Leonardo da Vinci.

Is this a useful tag? **If** we want to keep it and use it for simplification of algebraic equations, then  [simplification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplification) would be a better name.

Comment: To quote Frank the Rabbit, "Burn it to the ground".

Comment: I have [pinged the user](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712887/simplifying-optimization-problems-by-transforming-the-independent-variable#comment1830744_712887), who probably created this tag. Just in case he wants to defend why the tag is useful.

Answer (score 4):

> **Resolved(?):** [limit-theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit-theorems) has been merged into (renamed) [probability-limit-theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-limit-theorem). (There are surely a number of questions which should have this tag removed.)

The wiki of [limit-theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit-theorems) tag says "For question about limit theorems of probability theory, like the law of large numbers, central limit theorem or the law of iterated logarithm."

[Yeah, right.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit-theorems?sort=newest&pageSize=50) For calculus students, "limit theorems" means statements about limit of sum, product, etc. They vastly outnumber those dealing with limit theorems of probability, and they don't read  tag wikis.

I think if this tag is to survive, it has to be renamed to something less calculus-y. I suggest [probability-limit-theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-limit-theorem), which has 25 characters. (For the pluralization s, see Jeff Atwood.)

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Agreed. Tag names should be less vulnerable to misunderstanding, especially those that calculus students are likely to use. Starting the tag name with "probability" should make things clearer to first-time askers.

Comment: What about [probably-limit-theorems] instead? :-P

Comment: The state of the tag either called for a complete change in its definition, or at least a temporary change. The intent of the tag is now somewhat more clear by its name, though if better name suggestions pop up further changes can be made.

Answer (score 4):

Do we really need both [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) and [tag-management](/questions/tagged/tag-management) on Meta? Looks like almost all of 31 questions using the latter also use the former.

So I propose (tagging)←(tag-management)

Comment: Indeed, the description of (tagging) says: "If your post at meta is about suggesting new tags, choosing correct tags for some question, suggesting removal of some tag, this tag is appropriate for such question."

Comment: IIRC [meta-tag:tag-management] was created by [putting the tags tag-synonyms and tag-merging together](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-management/synonyms). Maybe we could keep separately the questions of the type *"What belongs into this tag?"* and the questions of the type *"Should these two tags be synonyms?"*, since they are somewhat different.

Comment: @Martin Well, it seems there are actually few questions of the type "What belongs into this tag?" — and they often also discuss wether this tag should in fact be a synonym of smth / removed altogether...

Answer (score 3):

> **Resolved:** [nullology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nullology) was removed from all questions, and the synonym suggestion has been deleted (before doing this it still appeared in the tag list). The tag no longer exists.

Apparently [nullology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nullology) is a thing. I think it shouldn't be.

(Maybe merge it into [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory) is a good idea?)

Comment: Shall we start by making the tag not a thing, or will that not suffice?

Comment: It should be obliterated from the utter existence of the universe. We will redo the big bang and slightly modify the starting conditions until this tag is no more!!

Comment: It seems that the [tag was added](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/12084/revisions) on several occasions (and maybe also created) by an experienced user. Perhaps it would be good to get his input. I left a comment on one of the posts he edited.

Comment: I created this tag.  I was probably in one of my more whimsical moods when I did so.  The intended use is not so much for elementary set theory question as the sort of questions like "Is the empty graph connected?" or "Why doesn't Bourbaki's definition of a topological space explicitly include the requirement that the empty set and the full set be open?" [Answer: because of conventions about the empty union and empty intersection which imply this.]  Such questions have a similar feel, and I thought that having the tag could be helpful to avoid duplication of content.

Comment: I admit that I then did not go back and systematically add the tag to anything like all of the questions on the site which concern nullology.  That would have been a lot of work, and in view of the somewhat unfortunate feature that changing a tag bumps a question, would have flooded the main page of the site with nullological questions, which is sort of the opposite of my intent.

Comment: But I still think the tag could be useful.  And it has a fun name...

Comment: Looking back at the very small number of questions which I tagged nullology, it seems like my own intention for the tag were not carried out very well: I apologize for that.

Comment: @Pete: Had I noticed this tag earlier, I would have probably raised the issue on meta earlier. I don't think that this tag is really needed.

Comment: @Asaf: I am sure that the tag is not really needed.  The question seems to be whether it could be useful to have it.  (Even there I don't have strong feelings...)

Comment: The questions currently tagged [tag:nullology] seem to all involve (elementary) set-theoretic aspects of $\varnothing$. Being a non-standard term, I really don't see any value in keeping it around. And no-one has expressed a strong desire to keep it around. Simply emptying the tag would appear to be a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @Arthur: I've proposed a synonym just earlier today.

Comment: @Asaf: If I understand your last comment correctly, you've seen the light and want me to delete the tag synonym suggestion.

Comment: I started emptying out the tag just now because I noticed it on a new question and it seemed to be just cruft. Only afterwards did I discover this discussion -- fortunately it seems that my actions align with consensus :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think that [parsing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) can be merged into one of the tags related to formal languages and whatnot.

Answer (score 3):

> **Resolved:** Synonym approved!

Is there a real difference between [sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) (four questions; no wiki and excerpt) and [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series) (plenty of questions, tag excerpt)?

My guess is that the former was a typo (someone clicked enter too fast), and we can delete it. But I'm not quite sure.

**Bump:** Can someone please [cast the last vote](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/sequences-and-series/synonyms)?

Comment: You may notice that both sequences and sequence are among [suggested synonyms](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/sequences-and-series/synonyms) for ([tag:sequences-and-series]).

Comment: @Martin: Thanks. At least one of them is now approved. Maybe we can merge the singular into the plural, and get it over with?

Comment: here you go...$ $

Answer (score 3):

I propose to merge the [morphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morphism) and [homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homomorphism) tags.

Comment: Since (proof-verification) and (solution-verification) have a [separate thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16973/), it would perhaps be better to make the suggestion as an answer to that post. And I think that's it not good to ask on several things in one post, unless they are closely related. (Suppose I would like to upvote one suggestion and downvote the other one. Would should I do? Even if I want upvote one of them and I am indifferent to the other one, it seems as my vote will be misinterpreted.)

Comment: In general, I do not expect too much feedback from the community about tags - many questions about [meta-tag:tagging] don't even reach 100 views. But there are exceptions and so let's hope this is going to be one of them. I have edited your posts so that there are now links directly to the questions tagged with these tags, so that users reading your post can easily check what kind of questions are these tags used for.

Comment: I will add that if this tags are made synonyms, (morphism) should remain master tag, since it is more general.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** Renamed. Tag Wiki (Stub) will appear soon.

[finite-elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-elements). What does it even mean??

---

If the purpose is finite <strike>elements</strike> (see Rahul's comment below) element method, then perhaps it would be a good idea rename the tag to [finite-element-method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-element-method), and if someone could add a wiki it will be great.

Comment: There is something called the finite elements method (FEM). I know nothing of what it is, but I suspect that is what the tag may have been created for, in which case it could probably bear a rename or becoming a synonym if the other exists.

Comment: @Willie: Thanks!

Comment: @Willie, Asaf: Actually, the term is [finite *element* method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method), no plural. Rename again?

Comment: @Rahul: Oops, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

We have [network](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network) and [network-flow](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-flow), both about the same size, neither has wiki or excerpts.

Do we really need both of them? (And can someone write a wiki for the one[s] we keep?)

Comment: I have posted some thoughts on ([tag:network]) tag [here in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14385558#14385558). (I did not wanted to put here too many long comments.)

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated reply.

Answer (score 2):

> Resolved

Here are two tags I noticed:

1. [classical-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classical-groups)
2. [linear-algebraic-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebraic-groups)

I have no idea if either is needed, but I suspect that the second one is too specific. Probably the first one too.

If other people can weigh in, and give their opinion is great. If these tags should stay, then they really need a wiki excerpt. Especially the first one.

Comment: Maybe classical-groups should stay. Maybe I'll try to write some tag wiki [stub] later...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that we remove the [oeis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oeis) tag.

Most of the 13 current questions in the tag deal with properties of specific sequences listed there (and so the [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series) is perfectly suitable). Of the remaining four, three are likely off-topic on math.SE and can be deleted:

1. [Calculate with sequences from OEIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/656406/8348)
2. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/801246/8348
3. [How do I determine if I should submit a sequence of numbers to the OEIS?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/892412/8348)

The remaining question

4. [Is the size of the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences bounded by aleph-null?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/762266/8348)

could/should be tagged [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory) and/or [cardinals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardinals).

---

This tag was [mentioned once in the Tagging chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9564716#9564716):

> [oeis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oeis) tag has been created [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/391727/3). I am not sure whether it is needed.  (Martin Sleziak)

Comment: I am not sure whether questions about usage of OEIS and OEIS itself should be considered off-topic. According to [help](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions about *software that mathematicians use* are on topic. We do have some questions about arxiv or wolfram-alpha, which are in similar vein as the questions you have mentioned. (On the other hand, I do not think that for the question where the tag was created it is very relevant that this sequence is listed on oeis.)

Comment: I have [pinged](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391727/effective-way-to-get-the-integer-sequence-a181392-from-oeis#comment1911483_391727) the user who  (probably) created this tag. It might be good to know also the opinion of the tag creator.

Comment: @Martin: My thoughts on the three questions I pointed as off-topic. (1) Borderline, at best. (2) Who cares? It's equivalent to "What MATLAB function has the longest name?" (3) If the OEIS has guidelines for submissions, those should be made [readily available at the OEIS site](http://oeis.org/FAQ.html#Z04).

Comment: How about we replace (oeis) with the pair (online-resources) + (sequences-and-series) for those questions listed?   [This tag pair](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-resources+sequences-and-series) correlates with OEIS pretty well. Then their topicality can be decided separately, without getting in the way of tagging decisions.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391727/effective-way-to-get-the-integer-sequence-a181392-from-oeis?noredirect=1#comment2187595_391727) is a reply from the (probable) tag creator.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I don't quite understand the tag creator's argument – what material difference does it make to a question, whether or not OEIS is referenced? And "but it is not possible to unite these questions except with a tag since the A number is not known in advance (and the question doesn't always write OEIS..." is rather weak, since searching `[oeis] oeis is:question` returns 11 of the 13 questions currently tagged (oeis).

Answer (score 1):

I think the diamond moderators should speed up the processes on changing the singular tag names to the plural tag names, as discuss in [About the plurality of tag names](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11960).

Comment: Diamond moderators _might kindly help_ — especially if you at least post a concrete suggestion (i.e. some list of tags needing pluralization). But really, I'm not sure this is that important...

Comment: You may find [this extremely simple data.SE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/revision/161459/205861/) helpful in finding tags you feel should be pluralised.

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at the tags at this (the meta) site, we have 6 pages of them and do we really need:

- [hat](/questions/tagged/hat),
- [retina-display](/questions/tagged/retina-display),
- [android](/questions/tagged/android),
- [ipad](/questions/tagged/ipad),
- [naming](/questions/tagged/naming)

and so on?

I am not sure what to do with them, probably best to make them synonyms of other tags or merg and delete them

Also many tags don't have wiki's , that in itself is with low used tags reason for investigation

Comment: Regarding [meta-tag:hat], see [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12371/8348) in the "Tag merging and synonyms" thread.

Comment: IMHO the device/OS/browser tags are quite useful when issues arise with using math.SE from specific platforms. These tags would help users search for information when they run into problems.

Comment: As for [meta-tag:naming], those two questions may be of historical interest, and those issues likely won't come up again. Perhaps an [meta-tag:early-history] or similar tag should be created to encapsulate these threads. I'm mostly thinking "out loud" about this one, though.

Answer (score 1):

A long long time ago, <del>in a galaxy far away</del> this thread happened:

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/should-we-have-a-lambert-w-tag/

Now I noticed that [lambert-w](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambert-w) exists with roughly 40 questions. Should we let it slide, and contribute that to the immense inflation of questions and users since then, or should we hold true to that thread?

(I have no opinion on the matter, for one, and my opinion on my lack of opinion is that it's weird.)

Comment: You're not alone in your lack of opinion, it seems.

Comment: The real question is whether I am alone on my opinion on my lack of opinion.

Comment: If the consensus in the other thread was that (lambert-w) is not needed and ([tag:special-functions]) should be used instead, the easiest way to go would be to make it a synonym of (special-functions). (Of course, with (special-functions) as the master tag.)

Comment: It's up to 58 questions now. I think it deserves to live, at least because it's actually being used correctly. Users are unlikely to type "lambert" into tag without knowing what they are doing. Some tag names are lucky like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think [operads](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operads) should perhaps be a synonym of [operad-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operad-theory), to be consistent with [group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory), [ring-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-theory) etc.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that [provability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/provability) exists with 24 questions.

Do we really need it? I'm inclined to say that it can be removed. But some more input is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

> **Resolved**: [laplaces-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laplaces-equation) is now a synonym of  [harmonic-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harmonic-functions)

We now have [laplaces-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laplaces-equation) tag with $59 $ questions (for the most part, it was edited into old questions). It should be made a synonym of [harmonic-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harmonic-functions), which has $280$ questions. I see no point in having one tag for a PDE and another tag for solutions  of that PDE.

Hence, I proposed [making it a synonym](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)

Comment: done <characters>

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks. There are other upvoted proposals in this thread that seem to require moderator action (renaming/merging). Is there a protocol for bringing them to a mod's attention for possible action or rejection?

Comment: um... if it does require moderator action, please flag. If the situation is within the specialties of one of the mods, we can certainly expedite it. If none of the mods are familiar enough with the subject to make a comfortable decision, we may hold off and watch the comments develop a bit before we act.

Answer (score 1):

Does anyone really care about the [systems-of-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systems-of-equations) tag?

Comment: I think it kind of makes sense when used in conjunction with *algebra-precalculus*. The latter tag is very broad, and solving a single equation vs. solving a system of equations are considered quite different topics at that level. So I don't see a particular need to remove it. There are only [five questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/209647/posts-tagged-with-only-one-selected-tag-plus-the-score-and-number-of-answers?Tag=systems-of-equations) with no other tags, two of which are closed.

Comment: (now all of those are taken care of)

Comment: This was discussed on meta in a separate thread: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9989/should-there-be-a-simultaneous-equations-tag The consensus was to keep the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Can anyone guess the use of [integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integers) and then retag/add a tag-wiki?

Or alternatively, we may remove the tag altogether.

Comment: Or make it a synonym of [tag:elementary-number-theory]. The latter tag is among the ones most frequently missed by new users, since "number theory" is not in their vocabulary yet, and "elementary" does not help.

Comment: I support integers→elementary-number-theory — but looks like I'm the only one who have upvoted this...

Answer (score 1):

What in the world is [unification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unification)?

Comment: Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29 (I don't think I have heard of it before.)

Comment: Something related to Sun Moon...

Answer (score 1):

What is [transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformation) about? No wiki. Questions involve:

- transformations of probability distributions
- transformations of differential equations
- transformation of conic section
- transformation matrices
- Fourier  transform, Abel transform, Hilbert transform, Laplace transform, Legendre transform, [any name] transform.
- any kind of linear transformation of anything
- any kind of nonlinear transformation  of anything

There are 939 questions, of them about 60 have no other tag.

What Is to Be Done? [Discussion here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17268/what-is-the-transformation-tag-for)

Comment: I'll add a link to the [separate question about this tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17268/what-is-the-transformation-tag-for), which was posted in the meantime. BTW thanks for [creating the tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1012685/revisions).

Answer (score 1):

There are three tag synonyms that were suggested but not discussed here. Since I doubt many people check regularly the ["suggested" tab of the tags page](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest), let me give them some exposure so that more people can vote on them:

- [point-set-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/point-set-topology) to become a synonym of [general-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-topology);
- [integrate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integrate) to become a synonym of [integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration);
- [natural-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-numbers) to become a synonym of [elementary-number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-number-theory).

The tag [continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuous) was suggested to become a synonym of [continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuity), and was [advertised here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/17390/10014), but it still lacks enough votes in either direction. (Recall that suggested synonyms are accepted at +4 and rejected at -2; anyone with a score of 5 on the tag can vote.)

Comment: Point set topology: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17904252#17904252

Comment: @Martin Point taken. But I don't think people check the chat often for things like that (I know I don't).

Comment: My comment was mainly intended to give some information on when and why was this synonym suggested. (And maybe to advertise that chat room at the same time.)

Comment: I just realized the [tag:natural-numbers] synonym was suggested in 2011... So there has probably been discussion about it, but I can't find it (cf. [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22natural-numbers%22)).

Comment: Some discussion on ([tag:natural-numbers]) in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2575681#2575681 (From 2011, as you correctly said.)

Comment: Echoing some of the concerns raised in that chat transcript, I'm not sure that the (natural-numbers) proposal is a good idea. It looks like a majority of the questions tagged (natural-numbers) aren't about number theory. Among the related tags in the sidebar, the set theory contingent is at least as prominent.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that [laplacian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laplacian) has been created recently, with two questions.

Being completely ignorant on the subject I have no opinion on whether or not it should be kept. But perhaps one of the other readers of this thread could weigh in.

(My default instinct is that we don't need more tags, and that tags should generally be discussed on meta before being introduced. So I'm naturally in favor of removing the tag, but I prefer if someone else judge on this.)

Comment: I noticed it, and my first inclination was to kill it (especially after [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/15226/)), but then I realized that harmonic-functions would not work for these questions. Harmonic functions and Laplace's equation refer to $\Delta u=0$. Questions about operator properties of $\Delta$  usually concern its engenfunctions, $\Delta u = \lambda u$. These are not harmonic functions. Spectral theory of Laplacian is a sizable field, so I think the tag may be viable. So: I'm inclined to keep Laplacian, but merge Laplace's-equation into harmonic-functions.

Answer (score 0):

What is the approximate difference between [approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation) and [approximation-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation-theory)?

(I really know nothing about the subject. I understand the difference between [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) and [probability-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-theory), but the volume of those tags is an order of magnitude higher, which makes it really justified to have two separate tags; is it the same here?)

Comment: Alright then. Thanks for cleaning up this issue. If someone can expand the tag excerpt a bit, it would be great.

Comment: Approximation theory is a sizable mathematical field, currently underrepresented here. But basic instances of approximation appear in calculus, e.g., "find an approximation to $\sqrt{4.01}$ using the differential". It is natural to tag this sort of question approximation, but classifying them as approximation-theory does not look natural to me.

Comment: Related discussion: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/what-exactly-is-estimation-theory

Comment: @Martin: Very related, thank you!

Comment: BTW the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/approximation-theory/info) lists some topics that belong to this tag.

Comment: I believe it should read "I probably understand the difference between proba$\dots$" based on "What is the appro$\dots$"

Answer (score 0):

Here are a bunch of new tags which I'm not sure are needed, but I can't really say. They are off shoots from the [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) tag, which may or may not be useful:

1. [algebraic-combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-combinatorics)
2. [analytic-combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytic-combinatorics)

(Most new tags are too general, too arbitrary, or too specific; but in this case both might be worth saving.)

Comment: My rule of thumb: if an area of math is significant enough to have its own Wikipedia article, then it can have its own tag, too. Both tags pass this test.

Comment: The one for algebraic combinatorics is not much of a Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

The tag [geometric-probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-probability) is meant for

> Probabilites of random geometric objects having certain properties (enclosing the origin, having an acute angle, being convex, ...); expected counts, areas, ... of random geometric objects.

In reality, it's often used for problems involving geometric probability  distribution  $P(X=x)=p^x(1-p)$, with no geometric objects involved.

Is there a way to rename the tag so that the confusion is avoided? I could not think of one. For now, I just edited the tag excerpt to point out that geometric distribution does not belong there.

In any event, this post is meant to raise awareness than this is one of the tags with substantial percentage of posts that don't belong there.

Answer (score -1):

Do we need [kalman-filter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kalman-filter)?

On the one hand the tag makes sense. In many occasions users ignore the tag excerpt, and just choose [filters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filters). In these cases I've been generally reassigning the tag to [signal-processing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing), so a new tag might make sense.

On the other hand, searching "Kalman filter" is simple enough, and it seems unlikely that a question about Kalman filters won't include the term "Kalman filter" in it. So the tag doesn't really add any advantage in this aspect.

(*Edit:* I have no actual issues with having this tag, but I would like more explicit support before I start retro-tagging questions; not just two downvotes and an obvious comment from Martin who started the tag.

For instance, if someone can suggest/post a tag wiki/excerpt it will be grand.)

Comment: I created the tag. My main two reasons were: 1) Very often such questions are incorrectly tagged (filters). 2) The notion of Kalman filter seems to be rather important (as far as I can say). A little more details in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17954818#17954818).

Comment: I know you have, Martin, and just when I told someone that I generally remove tags which weren't discussed on meta first. And you didn't bring it up on meta, I had to do that! Shame on you! :-)

Comment: Since you are asking about more community input, should someone (for example, me or you) create a separate question for this tag? Or is it sufficient that it is mentioned here? (So, hopefully, those users who follow the posts about tagging on meta, will eventually notice this post.)

Comment: @Martin: It seems that this post goes largely unnoticed. Perhaps wait out today, and tomorrow one of us should post a separate question.

Comment: Here is separate question about this tag: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16992/about-kalman-filter-tag

Answer (score -1):

> **Resolved:** [cauchy-seqeunce](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cauchy-seqeunce) is now [cauchy-sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cauchy-sequences) (without a synonym; one can be created if the singular pops up too frequently).

The tag [cauchy-sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cauchy-sequence) should be pluralized, for consistency with other tags (e.g., [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series).

Comment: Should this even be a tag? It seems rather pointless. Sequences should cover it well enough.

Comment: (sequences-and-series) grew to 13K questions, so having some more specific tags within it isn't unreasonable. They help the software pick what's more likely to be related.

Comment: Well when someone talks about sequences, they're often considering Cauchy sequences anyway.

Comment: In some abstract sense, maybe. Most questions in the general sequences tag are asked by users unfamiliar with the term "Cauchy sequence". The tag is applied to problems like "prove that if $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, then so is $a_n^2$" and the like. Those are a distinct group of questions.

Comment: Hm. That's a fair point.