# What to do when I see a new tag that is not useful?

Tags: discussion, tagging

The new tags "number" and "theory" were created at the same time tagging the same question leading me to believe that they are meant to be "number-theory". They do not contribute anything as tags so removing them may be a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Useless, duplicate, or misspelled tags are created often, and should be removed from questions. Users with 2K rep interested in having a somewhat sane tag system   may want to look at [the list of new tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) regularly and deal with miscreations such as

- [number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) created 1 hour ago
- [theroy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theroy) created 1 hour ago
- [differantiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differantiability) created 5 hours ago
- [solve-problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solve-problem) created yesterday
- [statistical](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistical) created yesterday
- ....

Just remove such things from questions, replacing them with appropriate tags. Having no questions left, a tag dies within 24 hours.

If you are unsure if the tag is useful or not, begin discussion on Meta, for example in [Tag cleanup 2014](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12485/).

[I dealt with those listed above, except *differantiability* was already gone by the time I saw it.]

Comment: I wonder what could be a sane tag in place of [tag:solve-problem] ;)

Comment: (differantiability) was a typo I made when retagging [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/944628/revisions), I managed to remove it during grace period. I avoided [the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/943256/revisions) with (solve-problem) tag since I did not want to put it into review queue by a trivial edit. I have also [removed (number)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17834433#17834433) from two questions yesterday, so I am surprised that it reappeared that quickly.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Tag and title edits do not put a question into Reopen queue; [source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/).

Comment: @DanielFischer In the specific case, nothing; but in general, [problem-solving](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving) exists.