# My first tag synonym suggestion. Did I do it right?

Tags: support, tag-management

I recently suggested that the [kaehler-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kaehler-manifolds) tag is a synonym of the [kahler-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kahler-manifolds) tag. Was this the right thing to do for these specific tags, and if so, should I mention the suggestion in [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12485/tag-cleanup-2014) thread?

**Added Later:** I just found a [discussion](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/390/21564) on MathOverflow Meta as to whether it should be [kahler-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kahler-manifolds) or [kaehler-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kaehler-manifolds). They decided to go with the former, whereas, thanks to Arthur Fischer, we now have the latter.

Comment: The fact that tags don't support diacritics in this day and age is saddening.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: There is limited support for [diacritics](http://french.stackexchange.com/tags/pr%C3%A9positions/info) and [non-Latin characters](http://russian.stackexchange.com/tags/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/info) in tag names. This is [allowed on a site-by-site basis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135955/214632), though likely judged on how necessary the extended character sets are for the community.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi An interesting read on this subject is [Technical Debt, a case study : tags](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/04/technical-debt-case-study-tags.html) by Marc Gravell,

Comment: Interesting point about MO tag. Thanks to the synonym, a question migrated from MO would have the tag remapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wouldn't've hurt to instead mention this proposed synonym in the Tag Cleanup thread, but that horse has left the barn. In general there is no *wrong* way to suggest a synonym (excepting perhaps yelling, "Make [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/this) a synonym of [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/that)!" at your computer, which is more ineffective than wrong). At worst your proposal just won't get enough support to be implemented.

I saw absolutely nothing controversial about the proposal and went ahead to approve it myself. I also agree with the user soon to be formerly known as Raff and swapped the "master" and "synonym" so that [kaehler-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kaehler-manifolds) appears as the tag.

Comment: Thanks. In future I will use the thread.

Answer (score 5):

I think it should be the other way around. In a medium that  does not support diacritics (such as tags) the proper spelling is Kaehler, not Kahler.